# Traversing a BFS in python

Tags: python-3.x, breadth-first-search

> Im trying to traverse a BFS but I continue to get an error. I believed I have 
>    followed the instructions correctly but I continue to get an error. 
>   create a Q with the root element, and an empty list
>   while there are nodes in the Q
>   grab the first one and add it to the result list
>   if there is a node to the left, add that to the Q
>   if there is a node to the right, add that to the Q

```
def BFS(self):
    if self.__value is None:
        return [None]
    Q = []
    Q.append(self)
    while Q:
        node = Q.pop(0)
        if node.__left is not None:
            Q.append(node.__right)
        if node.__right is not None:
            Q.append(node.__right)
    return Q
```

> This is the test case I need to pass.

```
    def test_BFS(self):
    bt = binary_search_tree([20, 10, 30, 25, 35])
    self.assertEqual(bt.BFS(), [20, 10, 30, 25, 35])
```

> This is the error I am getting AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != [20, 10, 30, > 25, 35]

Comment: Your code successfully *performs* a BFS.  It does not *return* a BFS, in fact it never returns anything other than an empty list, since it loops until `Q` is empty.  You need a separate list that you append the node values to (NOT the nodes themselves) as you do the traversal.

Comment: @jasonharper I thought I was doing that already. node = Q.pop(0) isn't that doing that? Can you give an example?

Comment: You need to return `[20, 10, 30, 25, 35]`, but you return `Q`, after `while Q` evaluates to be false (when its empty). So you return an empty list. Instead, keep a `result` list, and append to it as you traverse the tree, and return `result`.